# Как исправить ошибку при unzip в Ubuntu 18.04 - "an error occurred while extracting files"?

Tags: linux, zip

Есть архив. При распаковке вручную - появляется вышеуказанное сообщение об ошибке.
При распаковке через терминал - распаковывается,но все папки пустые. 
В самом архиве все папки просматриваются с содержанием.

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто, установить пакет 7zip-full